# How to open custom application page in a new window in SharePoint 2010

Tags: custom-form, edit-form

I have followed the below article in order to create some custom new/edit/view forms for a list

(http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.in/2011/06/sharepoint-custom-addeditdisplay-form.html).

Now in my newform.aspx page I have a submit button. Once I click that button I need to redirect to another page.

Problem here is that while the redirecting the new page is opening in a popup window. How can I open it in the current window?

Script used is below:

```
 private void PopupSendMail(string msg)
        {              
          string js = "<script language='javascript'>
            alert('" + msg + "');
            function load_url(externallink){
             window.open(externallink,target='_blank')}load_url('"+ mySiteWeb.Url +"');</script>";
            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "Register", js);
        }
```

Comment: Sorry - I'm not sure of what you want to achieve. Right now the page opens in a "popup window" but you want to open it as a "new window"? What is the difference? Do you intend to use the SharePoint modal dialog?

Comment: I want to redirect a page when user clicks on save button.. for example google.com. but here it is opening google.com in model popup?

Comment: so you actually want to open the link in the same page?

Comment: yes i want to open the link in a same page but not in a popup

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to open the page in the same window, while right now it is opening as a popup?

If this is the problem, just modifiy the target of the window.open command. Right now you have:

```
window.open(externallink,target='_blank')}
```

turn that to

```
window.open(externallink,target='_self)}
```

As you can see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) "_blank" means that the url opens in a new window.